# Join a table twice with different condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've a problem with this mysql query:

**Table group**:

```
--------------
ID      group
--------------
50      gr1    
51      gr2    
120     gr3    
121     gr4
--------------
```

**Table rel_group**:

```
---------------------------
ID      id_oth    type_rel
--------------------------- 
50      120         1    
50      121         1    
51      50          2
---------------------------
```

I need to get the result of the rows (specially 'group.group' and 'rel_group.type_rel') in which number 50 are either on ID column or at id_oth (both looking at rel_group table). I've got some partial results with this queries:

```sql
SELECT group.group, a.type_rel
FROM group
INNER JOIN rel_group a ON ( group.ID = a.id_oth )
WHERE a.ID = 50    

SELECT group.group, b.type_rel
FROM group
INNER JOIN rel_group b ON ( group.ID = b.ID )
WHERE b.id_oth = 50
```

But if I join both queries in one, the result is always 0 rows.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: @marcosh Sorry, but that query shows: gr1,gr1,gr2. And I need the following result: gr3,gr4,gr2

Comment: You shouldn't declare a table name as `GROUP` as its a keyword. And also avoid using table name as row name.

Comment: @G one Yes, you're right. It was just an example. My mistake

Comment: Can you post your expected output..

Comment: @G one. Yes, it was in the comment for marcosh. I want to get gr3(1st. row in rel_group table), gr4(for the 2nd.) and gr2 (the third one). Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's the one. Thank you so much. I can't vote for your answer because of my reputation. Sorry.

Comment: You don't need much reputation for accepting the answer. You can do that atleast:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting the output seperately from two queries, join them using **UNION ALL** as

```
SELECT Table1.group, a.type_rel
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN rel_group a ON ( Table1.ID = a.id_oth )
WHERE a.ID = 50   
union all
SELECT Table1.group, b.type_rel
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN rel_group b ON ( Table1.ID = b.ID )
WHERE b.id_oth = 50;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ccd8d/3)

Answer (score 0):

you can use and OR condition

```
SELECT group.group, a.type_rel
FROM group
JOIN rel_group a ON ( group.ID = a.id_oth )
WHERE a.ID = 50 OR a.id_oth = 50
```